# In Kuali Coeus, How can I add a new filed to the proposal development?

Tags: kuali

I want to add a new field to the proposal development, and it should be mandatory one, how can I add it? is it enough to add it to the data dictionary?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to add it to the data dictionary. You'll need to add it to the:

- database
- Java object model
- object/relational mapping metadata (OJB for KC<=5, in JPA for KC>=6)
- data dictionary

The recommended way of implementing additional fields is via "extended attributes". Each object managed by KNS/KRAD can have an arbitrary extension object attached to it with institution-specific data. Look to the [Kuali Financials Documentation section on Extended Attributes](https://kualico.atlassian.net/wiki/display/FINDOC/Extended+Attributes) or this [presentation on Creating an Extended Attribute](http://slideplayer.com/slide/7385942/).

I've added fields to our instance by subclassing DevelopmentProposal. The above steps are still necessary but it keeps the added field in the EPS_PROPOSAL table, so it's easier to write ad-hoc SQL against it. This way of doing things is not well supported by the software, and I would recommend sticking to extended attributes.